# How to find the sum of multiple select's selected options?

Tags: javascript

```
<select multiple name="item" style="width: 225px;" action="post" id="mySelect" onChange="document.getElementById('selectedValue').innerHTML = this.value;">
<option value="10">One
<option value="20">Two
<option value="30">Three
<option value="40">Four
<option value="50">Five
<option value="60">Six
</select>

<p>Total: <b><span id="selectedValue"></span></b></p>
```

I'm trying to get the total price displayed if multiple items are selected but it doesn't seem to be working for me. It's probably something simple but I can't get it. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where are the closing option tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`value` property stores the last selected option's value,  since you have a multiple `select` element, you can iterate through the `selectedOptions` collection of the `HTMLSelectElement` object:

```
document.getElementById('mySelect').addEventListener('change', function() {
    var total = 0,
        selected = this.selectedOptions,
        l = selected.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
       total += parseInt(selected[i].value, 10);
    }

    // ...       
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qoft7mre/

Comment: @vohuman Thank you. Just two other things, when I click the "reset" button I have on the page the current amount selected beside total eg. 10 doesn't clear, if their anyway to fix this so that it does? Secondly I tried changing values to 9.99 for example but the decimal places don't show up and it gets rounded down to 9? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Josh You are welcome. For the first problem you can listen to the `reset` event of the form and reset the content of the `#selectedValue` element in the event handler. For the second problem you can use `parseFloat` instead of the `parseInt`, i.e. `parseFloat(selected[i].value)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
onChange="document.getElementById('selectedValue').innerHTML = parseInt(document.getElementById('selectedValue').innerHTML || 0) + parseInt(this.value);"
```

This is not what you really want but you can sum like this.